# PyQtGraph SpotItem returns 'NoneType' when calling user data

Tags: python-3.x, qt, nonetype, pyqtgraph

I am trying to get the associated user data of a point (which is a `SpotItem` instance) in a scatter plot when clicked on it. While methods listed in the [documentation](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/_modules/pyqtgraph/graphicsItems/ScatterPlotItem.html#ScatterPlotItem) (like `pos()` or `size()`) seem to work fine, I recieve a `NoneType` object when I apply the `data()` method. I actually expected it to return my user data, but it doesn't.

So, how can I retrieve my associated original data that I put in?
What I actually need is something like an index `i` of the original input lists for a clicked point that would allow me to track back the corresponding `x[i]` `y[i]` set.

Here is my code sample:

```py
import pyqtgraph as pg

#some dummy data
x=[0,1,2,3,4,5,3.5,3.4]
y=[5,4,3,2,1,0,3.4,3.5]

win=pg.GraphicsWindow()
p1=win.addPlot(row=1, col=1)
my_data=pg.ScatterPlotItem(x,y,symbol='o',size=30)

p1.addItem(my_data)

def clicked(items,points):
    print("point data: ",points[0].data())


my_data.sigClicked.connect(clicked)
```

I am using Python 3.6 (with Spyder 3.1.4), Qt 5.6 and PyQt 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sigClicked` gave us the item (`ScatterPlotItem`) that has been pressed and the points (`SpotItem`) where they have been pressed, with the seconds we can obtain the element `Point()` that gives us the position, and this has the methods `x()` y `y()` that return the coordinates. From item we can get all the x and y that you have initially placed through `data['x']` and `data['y']`, respectively, then we have the points pressed and all the points possible so to find the indexes we use `np.argwhere()` and then we intersect the values with `np.intersect1d()`, at the end we eliminate the repeated points with `set`.

```
import numpy as np
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg


app = QtGui.QApplication([])

x=[0,1,2,3,4,5,3.5,3.4, 3.4]
y=[5,4,3,2,1,0,3.4,3.5, 3.5]

win=pg.GraphicsWindow()
p1=win.addPlot(row=1, col=1)

my_data=pg.ScatterPlotItem(x,y,symbol='o',size=30)

p1.addItem(my_data)

def clicked(item, points):
    indexes = []
    for p in points:
        p = p.pos()
        x, y = p.x(), p.y()
        lx = np.argwhere(item.data['x'] == x)
        ly = np.argwhere(item.data['y'] == y)
        i = np.intersect1d(lx, ly).tolist()
        indexes += i
    indexes = list(set(indexes))
    print(indexes)

my_data.sigClicked.connect(clicked)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I was looking for. So the `data` method needs to be applied on the `ScatterPlotItem` and not on the `SpotItem` and then it does return the associated user data. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
def clicked(items,obj, points):
    now_point = point[0].pos()
    x = now_point[0]
    y = now_point[1]
```

Then you can get what you want.